# Internal Architecture of ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I'm new to ROS so i got this doubt
what is the Internal Architecture of ROS
i mean how does it work in terms of process(node) management and all that stuff
Is it capable of doing all that an OS does

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54804/internal-architecture-of-ros/) by [Srinivas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4161/srinivas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2013-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [ROS Introduction](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Introduction) should get you started on all the concepts.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4